# Ionic 3 - Firebase current user is null

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

I am trying to get current user using `angularfire2`. In my `app.component.ts` file I have following code

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, ) {

  this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      console.log("not login");
    } else {
      console.log("login");
    }
  });

  this.initializeApp();
}
```

Now in my home page file I am trying to get with below code

**CommonProvide.ts**

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
}

getUid() {
   return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
}
```

**home.ts**

```
constructor(private cp: CommonProvider) {
   console.log(cp.getUid())
}
```

Now this returns undefined uid. Then I noticed that an ajax call goes that fetch user data from firebase. That's why my constructor got fired first before ajax end. If I run my home constructor after some delay I got response. Now how will I get usr id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by removing default root page in `app.component.ts` and setting it when response comes from firebase.

**app.component.ts**

```
 rootPage;
 constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, ) 
 {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       if (!user) {
          this.rootPage = LoginPage;
       } else {
         this.rootPage = HomePage;
       }
    });

    this.initializeApp();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will return an observable which will wait for the result.

```
getUid() {
   return this.afAuth.authState.map((auth) =>  {
      if(auth == null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return auth.uid;
      }
    });
}
```

and in home.ts you can subscribe to it

```
constructor(private cp: CommonProvider) {
   cp.getUid().subscribe(uid=>{
      console.log(uid)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is that we cannot access value outside the subscribe.

Comment: you can pass it like this `this.userId = uid`, but you need to check for its null state;